# MPI_scatter of 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I new to MPI and I am trying to write program that uses MPI_scatter. I have 4 nodes(0, 1, 2, 3). Node0 is master, others are slaves. Master asks user for number of elements of array to send to slaves. Then it creates array of size number of elements * 4. Then every node prints it`s results.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MASTER 0

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int id, nproc, len, numberE, i, sizeArray;
   int *arrayN=NULL;
   int arrayNlocal[sizeArray];

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

   if (id == MASTER){
     printf("Enter number of elements: ");
     scanf("%d", &numberE);
     sizeArray = numberE * 4;
     arrayN = malloc(numberE * sizeof(int));
     for (i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++){
       arrayN[i] = i + 1;
     }
   }
   MPI_Scatter(arrayN, numberE, MPI_INT, &arrayNlocal, numberE,MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   printf("Node %d has: ", id);
   for (i = 0; i < numberE; i++){ 
     printf("%d ",arrayNlocal[i]);
   }
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

And as error i get:

```
BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
PID 9278 RUNNING AT 192.168.100.100
EXIT CODE: 139
CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

Comment: `arrayN` should be an `int*` instead of `int` and `arrayN = i + 1;` should be `arrayN[i] = i + 1;`.

Comment: actually i have it that way, i just made a mistake while rewriting code, because i have my nodes as vm. I think the problem is with numberE because if i change numberE to 2 and if input is 2 the code works

Answer (score 1):

- In `arrayNlocal[sizeArray];`, `sizeArray` is not initialized. The best way to go is to broadcast `numberE` to every processes and allocate memory for `arrayNlocal`. Something like:

  ```
  MPI_Bcast( &numberE, 1, MPI_Int, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
  ```
- `arrayN` is an array of size `sizeArray = numberE * 4`, so:

  ```
  arrayN = malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
  ```
- `MPI_Scatter()` needs pointers to the data to be sent on root node, and a pointer to receive buffer on each process of the communicator. Since `arrayNlocal` is an array:

  ```
   MPI_Scatter(arrayN, numberE, MPI_INT, arrayNlocal, numberE,MPI_INT,MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  ```

or alternatively:

```
    MPI_Scatter(arrayN, numberE, MPI_INT, &arrayNlocal[0], numberE,MPI_INT,MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

- `id` is not initialized in `id == MASTER`: it must be `rank==MASTER`.

As is, the prints at the end might occur in a mixed way between processes. 
Try to compile your code using `mpicc main.c -o main -Wall` to enable all warnings: it can save you a few hours in the near future!

Comment: You have the 'root' argument missing in your MPI_Scatter calls.

Comment: @macelee : you are right ! I will correct this mistake which also occurs in the code provided by the asker. Thanks for your accurate remark !